# Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]Unknown reason for transform failure

Tags: rviz, ros-melodic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Linorobot running on a Raspeberry pi 4 and ROS 18.04 and a YDlidar.

It has been working without this problem for many months. I have not changed anything and this problem appeared in RVIZ a few day ago.

I have looked at the previous answers to this question but they do not apply to my case since my tf tree seems ok.

See the image below.

[image: image description]

When i echo the transform from /laser to /map
after two tries I get the transform echoed nicely

```
$ rosrun tf tf_echo /laser /map
Failure at 1634088802.435207342
Exception thrown:Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1634088802.397446394 but the earliest data is at time 1634088802.807524000, when looking up transform from frame [map] to frame [laser]
The current list of frames is:
Frame base_link exists with parent base_footprint.
Frame base_footprint exists with parent odom.
Frame imu_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame laser exists with parent base_link.
Frame odom exists with parent map.
Frame caster_left_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame caster_right_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame wheel_left_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame wheel_right_link exists with parent base_link.

Failure at 1634088802.435545412
Exception thrown:Lookup would require extrapolation into the past.  Requested time 1634088802.397446394 but the earliest data is at time 1634088802.807524000, when looking up transform from frame [map] to frame [laser]
The current list of frames is:
Frame base_link exists with parent base_footprint.
Frame base_footprint exists with parent odom.
Frame imu_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame laser exists with parent base_link.
Frame odom exists with parent map.
Frame caster_left_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame caster_right_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame wheel_left_link exists with parent base_link.
Frame wheel_right_link exists with parent base_link.

At time 1634088803.397
- Translation: [-0.358, 1.633, -0.180]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.977, -0.212]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.000, -2.715]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.000, -155.535]
At time 1634088804.397
- Translation: [-0.356, 1.634, -0.180]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.977, -0.211]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.000, -2.716]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.000, -155.601]
At time 1634088805.397
- Translation: [-0.353, 1.634, -0.180]
- Rotation: in Quaternion [0.000, 0.000, 0.978, -0.210]
            in RPY (radian) [0.000, 0.000, -2.717]
            in RPY (degree) [0.000, 0.000, -155.700]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/388556/transform-%5Bsender=unknown_publisher%5Dunknown-reason-for-transform-failure/) by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2021-10-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-13**:
Is this a multi-host ROS application? If it is, clocks may have drifted between the hosts publishing and subscribing. Especially with TF, that can cause the problems you describe.

**Comment by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) on 2021-10-13**:
In principle this should not be the issue. I have an ntp server in the mobile robot and chrony in the remote pc with rviz. If i check the synchronicity it is looking ok see below

```
chronyc tracking
Reference ID    : D8C59C53 (ntp.nyy.ca)
Stratum         : 2
Ref time (UTC)  : Wed Oct 13 19:31:41 2021
System time     : 0.000142170 seconds slow of NTP time
Last offset     : -0.000099168 seconds
RMS offset      : 0.212730974 seconds
Frequency       : 25.788 ppm slow
Residual freq   : -0.240 ppm
Skew            : 2.451 ppm
Root delay      : 0.051655117 seconds
Root dispersion : 0.015191648 seconds
Update interval : 64.4 seconds
Leap status     : Normal
```

As an additional point, if i add a screen to the mobile robot and also run RVIZ on this unique machine i still have the problem.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-10-14**:
Well it was one thing to check. I did not suggest it would be the one-and-only cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have finnaly solved it by simply installing the new version of the Ydlidar driver for ros (ydlidar_ros package ) for some unknown reason the old version package ( ydlidar ) was not working well anymore.

---

Originally posted by [frge](https://answers.ros.org/users/53783/frge/) with karma: 51 on 2021-10-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1